# How to merge a stash after removing a file locally and commiting the change?

Tags: xcode, git

Currently had issues with 'UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate' while working with another developer and using Git as our source control. I realized early on that .gitignore wasn't ignoring that file and I decided to remove/untrack it with 'git rm --cached'. Before executing the command, I stashed my current changes to:

1. Keep my current changes
2. Create a quick commit that reflects the removal of  `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`

I created the commit the reflected the removal of 'UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate' and proceeded with 'git stash apply'. This was the error that I received:

```
needs merge
unable to refresh index
```

I'm aware that the stash still has `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` but I was under the impression that Git would merge the newly committed state of the master branch with the stash and force me to resolve the `merge conflict`.

How would I be able to merge the stash to regain my previous work to the newly committed master branch the no longer has nor tracks `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`?

Comment: Side note: it's not the *branch* that does not have / does not track `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`. It's that there is a *commit* that does not have `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`. Checking out that commit means that `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` is not in your index, which means that is not tracked. Checking out some other commit that *does* have file `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` means that `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` is back *in* your index, which makes it tracked. In other words, it's the presence or absence of the file in the index that makes it tracked/untracked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you have a stash that won't apply, I recommend turning that stash into a branch.

To do that, first make sure you have no uncommitted work.  This means you should now commit whatever you're doing, or stash it—the latter is a bit ironic and weird but works fine, as long as you remember that the stash you're converting has now been renumbered.  Now that everything is "clean", pick the troublesome stash by its ID—`stash@{1}` or `stash@{6}` or whatever if necessary, or just the default if it's the current or only stash—and use that ID (or the default) as an argument to the `git stash branch` command:

```
$ git stash branch newbranch stash@{3}
```

You're now in a state where you can run `git status`, then maybe `git commit`, or `git add` and `git commit`, etc—your `stash@{3}` stash has been re-loaded into the index, as if you had run `git stash apply --index`, and into your work-tree as if by the same command.  Once you make the commit(s), your new branch is ready to be used however you like.

(In fact, Git really *did* run the command: first, Git ran `git checkout` of the appropriate commit.  Then Git ran `git stash apply --index` on the stash, which restored the saved index and the saved work-tree.  Then, having succeeded at the applying, Git ran `git stash drop` on that saved stash.)

In this case, after `git stash branch name stash`, you'll probably want one `git add` and `git commit`, which will save all of your work including the pesky not-removed, maybe-modified-maybe-not `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` file.  But now you can `git checkout` the branch you *were* working on, apply and drop the temporary stash you made if you made one, and `git cherry-pick -n` the commit on that new branch you made from your troublesome stash.  If that commit has no changes to the pesky file, and the pesky file doesn't exist here, the cherry-pick is likely to go pretty smoothly and you'll be all set.

#### Discussion

This all makes a certain amount of sense once you realize that (a) a `git stash` object is just a clump of commits; (b) commits always record their parent commits; and (c) a branch is just a series of commits designated by a branch *name* identifying the *last* commit that is to be considered part of the branch.

If the way `git stash` made its little clump-of-commits were normal, you'd have:

```
...--o--o--*--o   <-- your-branch
            \
             i--w   <-- stash
```

and hence the stash would really be just like any branch, except for the fact that `refs/stash` does not start with `refs/heads/` (compare with `refs/heads/your-branch`, which obviously does start with `refs/heads/`).  Here, `*` is the commit that you *were* on when you ran `git stash`.  You added one more commit, which is the one just to the right of the `*`.  The `i` and `w` commits here would contain the index and work-tree states as of when you ran `git stash`.

The tricky part is that `git stash` doesn't make `i` and `w` like this at all.  Instead, it makes:

```
...--o--o--*--o   <-- your-branch
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
```

That is, the saved work-tree state appears to be a *merge commit*, saving the result of merging your index commit `i` and the commit you were on when you ran `git stash` (commit `*`).  It isn't really a merge, in that it's not what you'd get by running `git merge`: the stash code is just abusing the merge-commit format, to make it easier for the stash code later.

Fortunately, `git stash branch` knows just how to de-abuse the format.  It:

- checks out commit `*`;
- makes a new branch name to remember where you are now; and
- applies the stash, keeping its index and work-tree components separate (just as they were when you saved the stash) in case that's what you intended.

So now you have:

```
             o   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--*   <-- new-branch
```

with `i` in your index (ready to be committed) and `w` back in your work-tree (ready to be `git add`-ed to update your index, after which `w` will be in your index and ready to be committed).  Commit `*`, of course, has the pesky file in it, so leave the pesky file where it is with no changes, add and commit everything else, and you get:

```
             o   <-- your-branch
            /
...--o--o--*--W   <-- new-branch
```

where `W` is a regular ordinary commit of the work-tree state you had, ready to be given to `git cherry-pick` (probably with `-n`) or used however you like.

Eventually, you can simply delete the branch `new-branch` (which you probably want to call by some other name) and commit `W` will be abandoned and will eventually disappear entirely.